# NullPointerException when trying to use store an object using JSF, Spring, and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, maven, nullpointerexception

I'm very new at using JSF, Spring, Hibernate, and Maven. But I so far created a simple project that takes in a first name and last name on a jsf page. Passes it to a managed bean > then passes it to a pojo on a separate module for my service tier. That all works, but now I am trying to implement hibernate into the project. I added a couple dependencies to my pom on my service tier, created some files in a resource folder (db.properties, applicationContext.xml, datasource.xml, HibernateSessionFactory.xml), and created a quick little dao file. The architecture is terrible, but I just want to get a quick example to work before I move on to designing a big project.

My application context file on my web tier just sets up my managed bean to connect to my service tier. It does not have any hibernate configs since I want to do all processing and database interaction on my service tier. Also, I am using hibernate annotations on my pojo.

When I run my server, I can access my webpage, type in the first name and last, and hit submit. When I debug through, it sets the variables from my managed bean to my service tier, then my service tier call addCustomer from a customerdao object. I get a null pointer exception on my getHibernateTemplate().save(customer); line.

```
WARNING: #{formBean.findBalance}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{formBean.findBalance}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.scott.common.test.Customer.save(Customer.java:52)
    at com.scott.common.CustomerBackingBean.findBalance(CustomerBackingBean.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 24 more
```

This is my HibernateSessionFactory.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>com.scott.common.test.Customer</value>
    </list>
    </property> 

</bean>
</beans>
```

This is my db.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scottdb
jdbc.username=djdjdi
jdbc.password=dldljdl

This is my datasource.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

 <bean 
   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
        <value>db.properties</value>
   </property>
</bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

This is my applicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

        <bean id="customerDao" 
             class="com.scott.common.test.CustomerDAO" >
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>

</beans>
```

This is my customerdao class

```
package com.scott.common.test;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;


public class CustomerDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport
{   
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        customer.setDescript("Test description");
        getHibernateTemplate().save(customer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You dump all of that, and yet do not tell where the exception is thrown. Try to submit an http://sscce.org

Comment: Its a null pointer exception. Here are the first two lines of the stack trace:

WARNING: #{formBean.findBalance}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{formBean.findBalance}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: If you see the above Indication in stacktrace formBean is null as per my guess.May be dependency Injection issue. Can you please remove `pom.xml` as it no use for this post and please post the full `stacktrace` and JSF spring Integration related stuff.

Comment: you need to show full stacktrace.

Comment: I updated this with the full stacktrace

Comment: You seem to never have learnt/developed basic Java before diving into JSF. Do you really not *understand* what that line means? `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.scott.common.test.Customer.save(Customer.java:52)`. It is basically telling that at line 52 of `Customer` class, inside the `save` method, some object reference is being accessed/invoked using the period `.` operator, while it is still `null`. If you try to access fields or invoke methods on a `null` object, you'll get exactly this exception.

Comment: Yeah I know what that line means. I've been programming in java for about 5-6 years now, but thats just been school experience. I want to further my knowledge by learning the web site of it and maven/spring/hibernate. The customer line 52 calls the addCustomer method on my dao class. When I debug, the exception gets thrown then I try to run the getHibernateTemplate.save(customer). by the way, the customer object is set with all required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - `customer` is probably `null`.  Try making this change, which checks if the customer object is null:

```
public class CustomerDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport
{   
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        if (customer == null ) {
            return; // do nothing if the customer is null
        }
        customer.setDescript("Test description");
        getHibernateTemplate().save(customer);
    }
}
```

Any time you invoke a method on an object that is null, you'll get a NPE.

Another option is to throw an Exception that is more helpful:

```
if (customer == null ) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("customer may not be null");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. customer is actually getting all of the correct data. What I think it is, is maybe my sessionfactory isn't getting set, but thats just a complete guess. These are the first two lines of the stack trace.

WARNING: #{formBean.findBalance}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{formBean.findBalance}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Just another guess -  probably Spring beans not properly initialized.
Try to check:

1. Is customerDAO created via Spring or somewhere explicit new
   CustomerDAO()?
2. Check in debugger sessionFactory and other
   session related properties.

**UPDATE**:
After looking into the code, the guess was confirmed: Spring was configured wrongly. There are 2 independent application contexts in 2 eclipse projects. Need to merge it into one (which is for web application).

Comment: customerDAO is getting set explicitly in my customer pojo (like I said architecture is just basic pojo and dao layer, not written to actually be a good design, just wanted to learn how to get spring, jsf, and hibernate to work together). After debugging, I can see that sessionFactory is not getting set. How can/should I set this, and what other ways can I check to see if my spring beans are being initialized properly? Thank you again for all of your help

Comment: You should inject customerDao (optimal way), or read customerDao/sessionFactory from the application context.

Comment: Ok, I can inject the dao (I'm assuming that is just by setting a property and ref under the dao bean declaration. the same way I am doing the sessionFactory). But how can I get my beans to get initialized? I know I can use Applicationcontext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path/to/file/") in a simple java project in my main method. But when I tried doing that in my dao, I have basically an infinite loop of errors.

Comment: Are you sure that context is not started properly? For web application  it is made in springapp-servlet.xml (Tomcat), it is easy to find example. Do not use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.

Comment: I have two separate modules (projects). My webapp which is jsf has a managed bean, applicationContext, and other required files. This module works and sets properties and sends the variables from my managed bean to a pojo in a separate module. This separate module has two classes (customer and customerDAO), db.properties, HibernateSessionFactory.xml, ApplicationContext.xml, and DataSource.xml. When the variables from my managed bean get passed to customer class(pojo), it sets values then calls the CustomerDAO.addcustomer(customer). In the dao, it does the getHibernateTemplate.save(customer).

Comment: 2 app context in one JVM? It's hard to help without seeing the code. Anyway we found a root cause - Spring context (which contains sessionFactory and CustomerDAO ) is not running.

Comment: I can send you the whole project if you want or is there a way to import onto here?

Comment: Please upload anywhere in web - dropbox etc

Comment: Ignore the naming conventions/architecture. It is not properly designed, I just wanted to learn what depencies/configs I needed for a basic hibernate project to work
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45475546/Program.zip